# Crop multiple images with variable height using convert

Tags: imagemagick

I have a list of images with fixed width but with variable height.

> 1440x2461
>
> 1440x2292
>
> 1440x2328
>
> 1440x2564
>
> 1440x2438

I would like to crop footer of the images by 380px from the bottom irrespective of the height of the image.

> 1440x2461 -> after crop -> 1440x2081

The real problem i am facing is that i can't every time specify what to keep after crop like this :

```
convert in.png -crop 1440x2081+0+0 out.png
```

So my question is : Is there a way to tell ImageMagick to keep unspecified area after crop and remove the specified area ?

```
convert in.png -crop -{command to invert selection} 1440x380+0+0 out.png
```

Or any other way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `- gravity South`. [IM Docs](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity).
It will tell to measure the offset from bottom.